# Project doesn't appear in Eclipse Project Explorer, and I can't import it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-project-file

I had a project that disappeared from the Project Explorer in Eclipse. I tried **Import** > **General** > **Existing Project into Workspace** and got an error saying `No projects are found to import`. Then I tried creating a new project and got an error saying that a project already exists there. `~/Eclipse/workspace/myProject overlaps the location of another project: 'myProject'`

What's going on? How can I make the project show up in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Eclipse is looking for Eclipse specific file in root directory like `.project` `.classpath` that may be missing in your scenario,try to create new work-space and switch there, and then try to import projects.

It may work for you, and if that don't work, try this:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Go to `workspace.metadata.plugins`
3. Remove `org.eclipse.core.resources`
4. Start Eclipse
5. Do *File -> Import*
6. *General -> Existing Projects into Workspace* and import all the project from the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The project handle that eclipse creates might have been deleted accidentally or corrupted.

If all the project source contents are intact on the disk, you can delete the files/foders that eclipse creates around the project that usually start with a 'period' (.project, .settings etc.) and then create a project with the same name.

You might find a solution on this post, check this you haven't already.
[Eclipse: Error ".. overlaps the location of another project.." when trying to create new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733089/eclipse-error-overlaps-the-location-of-another-project-when-trying-to-cr)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble.
What I did to fix it was:

- Create an empty java project with the right name
- Import project/General/File System, select the project in my workspace folder
- Select the empty project created before as destination
- Right click on project/Team/Share project/Select right git repository
- Right click on project/Team/Reset hard on master branch

Now I have the project in my Package Explorer.