# Suggestion to import eclipse project to my workspace

Tags: eclipse

I have imported an eclipse project to my workspace. While importing,I forgot to select "copy to workspace"check box. But now, I want those projects to be in workspace. Is there any way to achieve this without importing again.

Comment: Why don't you want to import this again? This would be the simplest way.

Comment: The number of eclipse project imported was more than 20, and all those project are in different location.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project in Package Explorer, Refactor, Move and select target location for your project.

Comment: Wow, I'm using Eclipse for ages, but haven't seen this feature before :D

Comment: I tried with providing target location as workspace location, but i am receiving "%target location % overlaps workspace location " any idea?

Comment: You can use any empty directory (not neccessary workspace location) to import your projects into. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594084/eclipse-import-project-error-overlaps-workspace-location).