# Eclipse Error: Overlaps the location of other project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a new java project in my workspace. But i am getting the following Error:

"Overlaps the location of other project"
My current projects in:

```
Documents/workspace/Folder/{projects(About 10 Projects)}
```

If i create a new project from Eclipse, the new projects are coming under:

```
Documents/workspace/{New Project}
```

I have tried to the following steps to resolve this mentioned in other posts in stackoverflow.com:
[Eclipse: Error ".. overlaps the location of another project.." when trying to create new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733089/eclipse-error-overlaps-the-location-of-another-project-when-trying-to-cr/11733123)

But i am not able to solve this. Can anyone help please?

Comment: How about answers in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594084/eclipse-import-project-error-overlaps-workspace-location

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fought this issue for a day and feel quite humble when I finally read all the post and figured out a good solution. This should be added to an Eclipse ten commandments... Thou shalt separate your workspace from your code and never the two shall meet. In that create the folder structure something like this:

```
C:\workspace\training\
C:\training\maven102-section1-initial-master\...
```

When you open Eclipse, point your Work space to the "c:\workspace\training" area. And for all your code, keep it in the "c:\training\maven102..." area.

My issue was having EVERYTHING ALL in the same folder, like a big old hoarder... and that does not work out either. Enjoy!